# SOLR: Join tokens into one

Tags: solr

I need to define a fieldtype which would 
1. take an input,
2. tokenize it (by whitespace), [**solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory**]
3. remove stopwords, [**solr.StopFilterFactory**]
4. replace tokens with synonyms [**solr.SynonymFilterFactory**]
5. join the tokens into one token [**?**]
6. Create N-Grams [**solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory**]

The only problem is step #5, Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: you want all the tokens plus one extra token that is the join of all the others?

Comment: This is a strange use case. If you give an example telling what you are trying to accomplish by this, someone may suggest a better alternative.

Comment: I'd like to understand it too. Could you give a text-example and explain what you try to accomplish?

Comment: I have implemented a custom filter for concatenating all the token. Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28903881/2254048). I know this might be late for you now.