# Solr Custom Filter for concatenating tokens

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to write a custom filter for solr analyzer phase. The idea is to first tokenize the input business name by whitespace then apply a set of filters for lower case, patterns replacement and removing the stop words. After these filters, I want to merge (concatenate) all the token into one token and then apply the NGramFilterFactory for generating N-Grams from the token.

The reason I want to combine the all the token (generated initially from business name) is that I would not miss the tokens (whose length is less then N, in NGramFilter) from indexing in the solr and user might not insert the proper spaces while entering the business name. Please let me know for more clarification.

I made an attempt to write one custom filter for the same but this is not working properly and I am able to understand the behavior of it.

When I query the name "apple" then it return n1 number of results.

when I query the name "computers" then it returns n2 results.

when I query the name "apple computers" then it returns n3 results.

when I query the name "computers apple" then it returns n4 results.

Here n3 < (n1,n2) and n3 != n4

Here is the code: I am using solr 4.10.2 version and included same solr-core jars.

```java
public class ConcatFilter extends TokenFilter {

private CharTermAttribute charTermAtt;
private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

public ConcatFilter(TokenStream input)
{
    super(input);
    charTermAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
}

@Override
public boolean incrementToken()  throws IOException  {

    if(input.incrementToken()) {
        int len = charTermAtt.length();
        char buffer[] = charTermAtt.buffer();
        builder.append(buffer, 0, len);
        char[] newBuffer = builder.toString().toCharArray();
        int newLength = builder.length();
        charTermAtt.setEmpty();
        charTermAtt.copyBuffer(newBuffer, 0, newLength);
        charTermAtt.setLength(newLength);
        return true;
    } else {
        builder.delete(0, builder.length());
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to fetch all the token at once, concatenate them and return a new token stream?

Comment: Why would you expect n3 == n4? Say, if your ngramfilter is generating 3-grams, n3 will include the terms `lec` and `eco`, while n4 will include the terms `rsa` and `sap`.  Also, does (n1,n2) mean something like n1 ∪ n2?  Or n1 + n2?  Long and the short of it is, not sure I understand exactly what the problem is.  Can you provide an example of a document that does match any of those queries that shouldn't, or that doesn't match and should?

Comment: As I understand from your description, concatenating the tokens would result in applecomputers and computersapple - where `n3 != n4` still would differ. Have a look at the shingle factory, and if possible, expand the question with your actual problem and not the solution you think you need.

Comment: @femtoRgon You are right. The values of n3 and n4 will be and should be different as they will generate different set of trigrams. (n1, n2) means either n1 or n2 number of results. This is just to compare the number of results returned by different queries. The queries, were to analyze the filter and to understand the behavior. Problem I am trying to solve is to concatenate set of token into one token. So that if different user put the same term differently it would always produce the same set of trigrams. I mean "apple computer", "applecomputer", "apple com puter" like wise.

Comment: I looked at the ShingleFilterFactory, It do combines the tokens with min and max shingle size params. But I want to generate only one output (token) out of all the tokens available in tokenstream. So how can at run time it can take the these params dynamically and generate only one token? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory. I want to combine the whole string "please divide this sentence" string as "pleasedividethissentence". Here each word from the string will be coming as separator token after tokenizing using "WhitespaceTokenizerFactory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the concatenate word filter and submitted the patch as well into solr community. Anyone facing the same problem can find it here: [ConcatenateWordsFilter](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7193)